# Use of LeaseVersion configuration in ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

In Cosmos changefeed, we can pass "LeaseVersion"  configuration in "ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder" class.

Default value is PARTITION_KEY_BASED_LEASE.

What is use of LeaseVersion EPK_RANGE_BASED_LEASE  ?

version : azure-cosmos-4.47.0

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/dabc6e2a350fcee92923484608dbe5eb6626a198/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder.java#L58), `LeaseVersion` seems to be `private`:

```
private LeaseVersion leaseVersion = LeaseVersion.PARTITION_KEY_BASED_LEASE;
```

This is set to `EPK_RANGE_BASED_LEASE` when using `handleLatestVersionChanges` or `handleAllVersionsAndDeletesChanges` (in BETA, this is the [Change Feed "All Versions and Deletes" preview mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/change-feed-modes?tabs=latest-version#all-versions-and-deletes-change-feed-mode-preview)).